# Round midpoint values based on proportion table in R

Tags: r

I've got a numeric variable in the range from 1 (min) to 5 (max). The value ranges across 8 different variables. Therefore, the first row would look like this:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8
4    4    1    4    5    4    4    1
```

I've computed (row-wise) a median value for each row across the 8 variables. Occasionally, the median will be a midpoint value, for example, 4.5 (since it's even number of variables). Therefore the resulting row might look like this:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Median
1    2    3    4    5    5    5    5    4.5
```

When I call table on each median value calculated in Medina variable, I'll get this:

```
    table(df$Median)
  1 1.5   2 2.5   3 3.5   4 4.5   5 
  2   3  10   5  25  17  75  53  87
```

**The issue** I am trying to overcome is that I wish to "get rid" of the midpoint/decimal values by including them in the nearest nondecimal values; however, if I simply use `round()`, then I end up biasing the values (as by definition the 4.5 is really in between), like this:

```
table(round(df$Median))
1   2   3   4   5 
2  18  25 145  87
```

What I was thinking of doing would be to round values based on the proportion of non-decimal numbers in the table (excluding the midpoint values):

So I would get proportion of non-decimal numbers using dplyr filter functions:

```
df %>% filter(median %% 1 == 0) %>% 
select(median) %>% table() %>% prop.table()
```

To get:

```
         1          2          3          4          5 
0.01005025 0.05025126 0.12562814 0.37688442 0.43718593
```

Next step requires constructing a function that will take all midpoint values in the median variable and round them to their nearest non-decimal values while keeping the proportion of the non-decimal variables intact or close to the original one. For example, 4.5 nearest values are 4 and 5, so it would have a chance of going becoming 4 based on proportion 0.37688442 and 5 based on proportion 0.43718593. This way I would transform midpoint values to the whole; however, it would not be as biased as using simply `round()`.

*An alternative approach is to split the value equally between 4 and 5. So 50% of variables with value 4.5 will go to 4, 50% will go to 5.*

I am thankful for any suggestions that would help me to solve this problem or get to the point I can start developing the function.

**Edit1. Provided my own attempt to answer this question.**

**Edit2. Provided data.**

```
dput(head(df, 15))

 structure(list(uniqueID = c("R_AtXpiwxKPvILFv3", "R_2xwP4iz6UAu1fTj", 
"R_b8IXGRKHP58x7GR", "R_ZelynHN8PCxxYyt", "R_PNjIc7h4dHebRgR", 
"R_2bTZvYLUuKNC22D", "R_3iLqwuDs493HstB", "R_291dITimLKjYXeL", 
"R_YWWGleFLxlIYzrX", "R_3st91vjNWNXlTHt", "R_3Mm8P52gaaxIpwD", 
"R_3MxHXTnrncpgnB8", "R_1LqDx1uxReOQHvO", "R_vJEGJDmbqdfO7qF", 
"R_3q8Wl8qys6nqxBH"), Median = c(4, 4.5, 
1, 4, 5, 4.5, 4, 1.5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 2, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5)), .Names = c("uniqueID", 
"Median"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: For the alternative approach, I would rely on randomness. Randomly add either 0.1 or -0.1 to every median and then round. Very simple, the result will not change for integer values, and the midpoint values will be randomly rounded up or down. You could adapt this to your first approach, but it seems like a lot of complication and potential bugs for very little gain.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to do something along the lines and edited the post. It's not very elegant but it does the job...

Comment: That doesn't really seem like part of the question, it seems like a solution. You should post it as an answer! But also, why aren't you rounding? I thought your goal was to get rid of the decimals, and the point of moving the decimals away from .5 was so that they would round nicely.

Comment: That said, if you want help improving the elegance of your answer, post some sample input in a copy/pasteable format (either use `dput` or share code to simulate it) and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Gregor I've edited it and posted it as an answer. Thanks for the comment. I've also added rounding. I'll try to create a reproducible code example, just need to check how `dput` works. Thanks!

Comment: `dput` is easy - if you have an R object, say `x = matrix(rnorm(9), 3)`, then you enter `dput(x)` and it gives you a copy/pasteable way to create that object, with all the values, class, and structural information. You don't need a big sample data set, if you already have data named `dat`, then `dput(head(dat))` is probably plenty.

Comment: Added head of data. I'll start to use `dput()` in any future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement it like this:

```
round_randomly = function(x, tolerance = 1e-6) {
    round(x + sample(c(-tolerance, tolerance), size = length(x), replace = TRUE))
}
```

Calling your sample data `dd`,

```
table(round_randomly(dd$Median))
# 1 2 4 5 
# 1 2 8 4
```

Any `tolerance` value less than 0.5 will work the same if your data is only integers and 0.5. If you have more continuous data, a smaller tolerance is better (to prevent, say 4.4 from being jittered up to 4.51 and being rounded to 5). I set the default to `1e-6`, which seems reasonable, a value > 4.499999 might get rounded up to 5.

Your answer goes to quite a bit of trouble to only add a random value to the midpoints - this isn't necessary because of the rounding. If the original value is 4, `4.000001` will still round to 4. Even if you set the tolerance to 0.4, `4.4` will still round to 4).

My method makes no guarantees about rounding *exactly* 50% of midpoints up and 50% down, but each midpoint is rounded up and down with equal probability. Unless you have very little data and an unusually skewed random draw, that should be close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Following suggestion from comments, I've attempted to create a function that randomly adds 0.1 or subtract 0.1 from all median midpoint values. It's not exactly the most elegant function ever but it does the job. One issue with the approach might be that randomization occurs by randomly sampling fraction of the dataset and adding 0.1 to it. Therefore, remaining unsampled fraction automatically gets to be subtracted by 0.1. It would be more elegant to do this for every value individually but I would have to explore this option.

*The function:*

```
randomize_midpoint <- function(dataset, new_random_median) {
  # Prepare variable for mutate
  new_random_median <- enquo(new_random_median)
  # Get Sample A
  sample_A <- dataset %>%
    filter(Median %% 1 != 0) %>% # get midpoint values
    sample_frac(0.5, replace = F) %>% # randomly sample 50% of them
    select(uniqueID, Median) # anti_join will need some unique identifier
  # Get Sample B by anti_join
  sample_B <- dataset %>%
    filter(Median %% 1 != 0) %>%
    anti_join(sample_A) %>% # anti_join automatically uses uniqueID
    select(uniqueID, Median)
  # Create opposite of %in%
  "%w/o%" <- Negate("%in%")
  # Mutate median according to conditions in case_when()
  dataset %>% mutate(
    !!quo_name(new_random_median) := case_when(
      uniqueID %in% sample_A$uniqueID ~ round(Median + 0.1),
      uniqueID %in% sample_B$uniqueID ~ round(Median - 0.1),
      uniqueID %w/o% c(sample_A$uniqueID , sample_B$uniqueID) ~ Median
    )
  )
}
```

The output of the function to compare with previous `table()`:

```
  randomize_midpoint(dataset = df, new_random_median = random_med) %>%
  select(random_med) %>%
  table()
```

Will return:

```
 Joining, by = c("uniqueID", "Median")
  1   2   3   4   5 
  2  16  36 110 113
```

Previous table:

```
table(round(df$Median))
1   2   3   4   5 
2  18  25 145  87
```